# Firebird permission denied when connecing with FlameRobin but is okay with isql

Tags: firebird, flamerobin

I'm trying to connect to employee.fdb in Firebird3.0 (localhost) using FlameRobin 0.9.3 on a Ubuntu OS.

The connection to Firebird using isql has no issues.  I can create users, roles, etc all from the terminal.  However, when I attempt to make a connection using FlameRobin I receive a 335544344 "Error while trying to open file Permission denied" response.

This occurs with the SYSDBA profile and any other new user profiles that I create in isql.  I can even create new users in FlameRobin but I cannot connect to any database.  I've verified in /etc/firebird/3.0/firebird.conf that DatabaseAccess = Full and have attempted to access the db from a couple different folders in case this is a read/write issue.  No success.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Any thoughts?

**Added info in response to Mark (4/26):**

The db is stored in */var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/.*  I have assumed this to be the default location for Firebird DBs and that the server automatically has access to it, but I suppose that might not be the case.  Is there a way to confirm server permissions to this directory and/or is this the customary spot to store work?

**Terminal Connection with ISQL:**

```
daniel@daniel-desktop:~$ isql-fb
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> connect '/var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/employee.fdb' user sysdba password 'xxxxxxx';
Database: '/var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/employee.fdb', User: SYSDBA
SQL>
```

**FlameRobin Database Registration Info:**

[image: FlameRobin_DB_Registration_Screenshot]

**FlameRobin Error:**

[image: FlameRobin_Error_Screenshot]

Comment: Please show exactly how you connect using FlameRobin, and how you connect using ISQL. My guess is that you're using the embedded mode with ISQL, and connect through a server with FlameRobin, and the server doesn't have access to your database file (eg because it is in your user folder, instead of a location where the server user has read and write access). When using Embedded mode, Firebird accesses the database with the access rights of your user, not of the server process.

Comment: Added connection info to question contents in response to @MarkRotteveel.

Comment: In ISQL you would probably get the same error if you use `connect 'localhost/3050:/var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/employee.fdb' user sysdba password 'xxxxxxx';` to connect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions issue as @MarkRotteveel suggested.  Problem was that I installed the server as a user and not as root.  Problem solved by removing and reinstalling both Firebird and FlameRobin as root.

Comment: was not necessary for FlameRobin. That is one of the points of SQL interfaces - to work with data not with files